# Create and Utilize a Vista VHD via Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, vhd

I have a windows 7 base install and a windows 7 vhd.  I am attempting to create the scenario where when I boot up I have the option of loading the windows 7 base, the windows 7 vhd or a vista vhd.

I used virtual PC to create a vista vhd and then used bcdedit to set up that vhd as an option on start up.  When I select that option though it goes to a repairing installation screen, fails and asks to restart (repeats if i try and select that option again).

Anyone know either
a) what is happening in my situation and what i can do to fix it
or
b) a good tutorial/reference on how to create and use a vista vhd from windows 7

I am trying to boot directly from the VHD.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether you're trying to boot the VHD in a VM or just on a physical machine.  Windows 7 supports booting from a VHD (without running in a VM.)  Vista does not, even if you're using the Windows 7 boot manager which does understand VHDs.

Comment: do you know of any official documentation that states that?  i from what i've seen it looks like that is the case, but would be nice to have a microsoft link/doc that states it.  (particuarly as it appears to at least boot up from the vista vhd, just that it always trys to go to "repair" mode)

Comment: I don't generally track the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

have you seen the wim2vhd app, if not then get it and hopefully you have the vista source media with image.wim file.  If so then follow the wim2vhd steps to create the vhd file.  then goto  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299(WS.10).aspx